# Unable to Retrieve Data from Bullhorn to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, google-cloud-dataflow, cdata, connectivity, data-integration

I'm trying to connect Bullhorn using Cdata to Power BI. While connecting to Power BI, I noticed couple of saved views shows blank or no data in Power BI.
Can anyone please advise how do I pull data from Bullhorn to Power BI and view all the required information's pertaining to reporting.

I have been trying to connect from more than a week.
Expecting to flow Bullhorn data to Power BI.

Comment: Suggest you contact CData support since you paid for their product/service. Otherwise, Bullhorn has an API and you could look to connecting to their API from Power BI.